# Why the array_rand() is not returning me the expected array output?

Tags: php, arrays, random, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've an array titled `$all_events` as follows :

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 201
                    [view_id] => 0
                    [is_featured] => 0
                    [is_sponsor] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 235
                    [view_id] => 0
                    [is_featured] => 0
                    [is_sponsor] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 236
                    [view_id] => 0
                    [is_featured] => 0
                    [is_sponsor] => 0                   
                )

        )

    [msg] => Success
)
```

In resultant array I want any two elements from the inner array`['data']` so for it I written following code :

```
$new_arr = array_rand($all_events['data'], 2);
print_r($new_arr); die;
```

I got following weird output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
)
```

The expected result should be as follows(if first and last elements are selected randomly):

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [group_name] => 
                        [event_id] => 201
                        [view_id] => 0
                        [is_featured] => 0
                        [is_sponsor] => 0
                    )        

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [group_name] => 
                        [event_id] => 236
                        [view_id] => 0
                        [is_featured] => 0
                        [is_sponsor] => 0                   
                    )
)
```

Why so?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem ? What do you expect to get? Did you read the manual?!

Comment: @Rizier123 : I've added the expected output if first and last elements are selected randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive array of keys. From the doc

> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random
>   entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned.
>   This is done so that random keys can be picked from the array as well
>   as random values. Trying to pick more elements than there are in the
>   array will result in an E_WARNING level error, and NULL will be
>   returned.

User this code

```
foreach(array_rand($all_events['data'], 2) as $key)
    $new_arr[] = $all_events['data'][$key];
print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: And what is OP's expected result ?

Comment: i am sure he want tow ramdom items

Comment: I've added the expected output if first and last elements are selected randomly.

Comment: @splash58 *I'm sure* from what? I don't see anything of OP's expected output in his original question.

Comment: @splash58 :I'm getting only one array element as output, I need two.

Comment: Now it's giving me the proper result. But does it give different, random result every time?

Comment: @user2839497 yes, array_rand must give random set of keys

Answer (score 0):

`array_rand(array,number)` **returns a random key from an array, or it returns an array of random keys if you specify that the function should return more than one key.**

```
$new_arr = array_rand($all_events['data'], 2);
```

**$new_arr** is an array include random index of $all_events['data']. If $new_arr like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
)
```

It means random values are $all_events['data'][0] and $all_events['data'][2].

If you need to get random values from `$all_events['data']`, Try following code.

```
$new_arr = array_rand($all_events['data'], 2);

foreach($new_arr as $index){
    print_r($all_events['data'][$index]);
}
```